# VS2012 required interface turning into provided interface in the UML Model Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2012, uml

Drag a required interface onto a component diagram (its the half circle one).
Check the UML Model Explorer, it turns into the full circle provided interface icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer, but it looks like this might be "working as intended".

All interfaces pulled from the UML Model Explorer are open circles, and when you click on the interface after dragging it to the canvas, there is a context icon that shows up next to the open circle. Click on the icon to convert the open circle to a half circle.